# Trouble importing keyboard with vs code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip, python-import

I am having trouble using VS Code with importing the keyboard module off of Python. I have seen it work within the terminal and have found it within the Python file in file explorer, but VS Code has not been able to recognize that I have it installed.

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of Python installed? Make sure VS Code is using the version that you used to install `keyboard`.

Comment: I only have Python-3.9.1 installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have installed the keyboard package in the global python environment.

So, then you should choose the global environment in the VSCode. Or install the keyboard package in the environment which you chose in the VSCode.

You can get which environment you have chosen through the status bar on the bottom left:

[image]

And you can get more information on the [official docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment).